# Update values when sending to another component Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I'm using routerLink to send an id from a component with a list of restaurants to another component via URL

```
[RouterLink] = "['../ restaurant-menu', restaurant.id]"
```

In the other component I use the id as follows

```
ngOnInit () {
  this.restaurantId = this.router.snapshot.params ['id']
  this.getRestaurantMenu (this.restaurantId)
}

restaurantMenu: void []

getRestaurantMenu (id): void {
this.RestaurantsService.getRestaurantMenu (id)
    .subscribe (
        restaurantMenu => this.restaurantMenu = restaurantMenu,
        err => {
            console.log (err);
    });
}
```

Everything works fine the first time I click a restaurant and load its menu, the problem begins when I return to the list of restaurants and click a different restaurant, the app loads the menu of the first restaurant I clicked, I have to refresh the browser Manually to load the correct menu.

I doubt that the id could be updated after calling the function getRestaurantMenu() because no matter how many times I leave and enter into different restaurants it will always show the menu of the first restaurant, but I also tried to do this on the HTML:

```
<P> {{restaurantId}} </ p>
```

And the id number displayed is correct. I tried different ways to pass that id but the result is the same, what could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: where are you defining `This` and why aren't you using `this`? Also not sure how `GetRestaurantMenu()` is ever being called as you are calling `GetRestaurantMenu(...)` instead of `this.GetRestaurantMenu(...)`.

Comment: Also is your `NgOnInit()` being called by angular? I thought it had to be called `ngOnInit()`

Comment: yeah, my fault while I was copying the code, sorry, I already corrected it

Comment: what does `RestaurantsService.getRestaurantMenu()` do?

Comment: It connect to an API to get the menu

Comment: I'm curious, when you say "go back to the list" do you actually mean navigating away, or is the list on the same page. If it is on the same page, you may be running into this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9811#issuecomment-264874532 which is basically that if you load the same route with different parameters, the component isn't reloaded... you have to manually subscribe to param changes or do some other trickery to handle it correctly. That slip has lots of details.

Comment: @YonaAppletree what you suggested works, I think that there must be a better solution but I'll use this until I find it, thanks

Comment: Ah, I didn't actually mean for you to use the reload solution, there are better ones on that page. I ended up using the trick where you do an intermediate route to a different component, described here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9811#issuecomment-248043993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve this, the problem was in the service to get the menu not in the component, here is the solution:

[angular 2 service is not updating params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384050/angular-2-service-is-not-updating-params)

if anybody else run into this problem this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try not to use `snapshot` but `ActivatedRoute` instead :

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";

...

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {  }

...

ngOnInit() {

  // (+)param['id'] to convert string to number
  this.route.params
    .switchMap((param: Params) => this.RestaurantsService.getRestaurantMenu(+param['id']))
    .subscribe(
      restaurantMenu => this.restaurantMenu = restaurantMenu,
      err => console.log (err)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did what is suggested here
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9811#issuecomment-264874532
the restaurantMenu component stays the same but in the restaurantList component I added this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
  ...
  openMenu(restaurant) {
    this.router.navigate(['../restaurant-menu', restaurant])
      .then(() => window.location.reload())
  }
```

and on the restaurantList HTML I added a `(click)="openMenu(restaurantId)"` It reloads the new page automatically and the id is updated, its a little tricky solution but works and I'll use it until find a better one.